# Can't log in to Stack Overflow using GitHub

Tags: support, login, github

It's been a few years since I've logged into stack overflow, and I used to log into Stack Overflow by using the "Log in with GitHub" option. This option does not seem to be there any more. Is there a way to login into my old account still?

Using the email I use with GitHub doesn't work, and it doesn't send a verification email when I try to reset.

I can still find my account, and I would love to use the same account with my existing trophies.

Comment: Use the contact form, support can merge your account

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've never had a GitHub login option on Stack Overflow as far as I recall.

But, we should be able to still sort this out - drop us a line via the [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) page, describe the situation, which email(s) you may have used, etc. and one of our support folks will get back to you ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357589/lost-my-login-via-github-account?noredirect=1#comment1194728_357589) for a possible resolution. I think in my case, the root cause was an apparent change of email on my GitHub account:

There was a dropdown menu in my GitHub account profile with my mail address that has somehow changed to an empty entry.