# Cannot log in to the Stack Exchange Android app with a GitHub login

Tags: support, bug, android-app, login, github

I have my Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange account linked from GitHub, so *when* I log in, I do it using the log in with GitHub option. Now I'm trying to log in to the mobile Android app and am not able to do it.

So within the app: Sign Up or Log In → Log In → Log in using another OpenID → Log in with GitHub prompts the correct GitHub login portal, but after providing the correct credentials I only see a page with "OOOPS Looks like something went wrong!"
I still get my device verification email from GitHub, but I'm not given anything to enter that code to.

This has been the case for three days now, so probably it is not just a temporary issue.

Is there another way I can log in or a fix for this?

EDIT: So apparently I had my Google account linked to my Stack Exchange account as well and was able to log in with that, if anyone else comes across this problem you can try that.

Comment: Given that the Android app is basically abandonware at this point, there's no guarantee that any of this will work or be fixed.  You're better off at this point using the responsive mobile site instead.

Comment: Does this help: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306721/282094 ?

Comment: @Rob That's an old question, referring to a user that was logging in with GitHub OpenID. We do now officially support GitHub OAuth logins on Stack Overflow. I don't know exactly how it works, but I highly doubt our API even has pathways to input device verification codes when needed. Even if we added them, those apps would never get updated to support their input. So it's unlikely this pathway will ever get fixed, Lauri.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the clairification, I didn't know so it was offered as a suggestion; rather than proposed as a duplicate. Since it's the Android APP logging in using Google seems like a good idea, and a method that they may not wish to use. Probably the contact link is needed to switch the login method, more of a guess than an answer ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Android app is no longer supported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)