# Lost my "Login via GitHub" account

Tags: support, login, github

I see there are a lot of folks in the same boat as me: All badges and credits (few, but hard earned) are now lost!

My account that was created as "Login via GitHub" is mysteriously unavailable to me. It can still be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3697584/themadsen), but I was forced to create a new (empty, noob) account when trying to login via GitHub just recently.

As advised [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306721/cant-login-to-stack-overflow-using-github) I tried the "contact us" page, but to no avail.

Stack Overflow, please advise!

Comment: Where are you trying to log in? https://stackoverflow.com/users/login is the only place you can use GH to log in. It's only active on SO itself, nowhere else on the network.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what that means, but yes, that is the place

Comment: So, if you go to that link, you can't log in with the GH option? Can you add an image of that page to your question?

Comment: No need, I just land in my new, empty account (That is also used for posting this). Also: I see that one can request a merge of two accounts via a so-called "contact form" but I can't see that anywhere. Is this the way to go? Where do I find it if yes? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @FlemmingMadsen Did you change your email on Github recently by any chance? I see this account is likely yours, but it has a slightly different email credential and was signed into via Google, not GH: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3697584/themadsen.

Comment: You have to log out or view that page in a private window or a browser where you aren't logged in to see it and try to log in with GitHub. The Contact form is at the bottom of every page in the footer. It says "contact".

Comment: @FlemmingMadsen I'd suggest trying to log in with Google (I'm not gonna put the email address in a public comment, but let's just say the domain name is the same as for your GH email you listed). See if that gets you into the right account - if so, you can merge the new GH-based account with that one via [the Contact Us page](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) (there's an option to merge profiles there) and then you'd be able to log in with either provider.

Comment: @AdamLear. Holy moly, it worked. Thanks so much. I believe the problem was that the github mail address was not a real one, but worked via a "star alias" on the domain. I now created the user for real in order to use Google oauth and was thus able to receive both confirmation emails. Thanks again

Comment: @FlemmingMadsen No problem. Glad to hear things worked out!